# How to only send certain requests with Tor in python?

Tags: python-3.x, tor

right now i am using the following code to port my python through tor to send requests:

```
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9450)

socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

I put this at the front of my code and then start sending requests, and all my requests will be sent through tor.

In my code I need to send a lot of requests, but only 1 of them needs to actually go through tor. The rest of them don't have to go through tor.

Is there any way I can configure my code so that I can choose which requests to send through tor, and which to send through without tor?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of requests? If those are HTTP requests and not using keep-alive, your socket is closed after each request. Thus you'd need to repeat the code above for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of monkey patching sockets, you can use [requests](http://python-requests.org/) for just the Tor request.

```
import requests
import json

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

data = requests.get("http://example.com",proxies=proxies).text
```

Or if you must, save the `socket.socket` class prior to changing it to the SOCKS socket so you can set it back when you're done using Tor.

```
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9450)

default_socket = socket.socket
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
# do stuff with Tor
socket.socket = default_socket
```