# cannot connect to tor service with python3

Tags: python-3.x, tor

i have python3, urllib, socket, socks and tor in my ubuntu,i set proxies with '127.0.0.1:9050' to get web page through tor, when i use it to get the hidden service by this proxies, it came an error like 'urllib.error.URLError: ' ,how can I get tor hidden service with python3

Comment: the error is urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General SOCKS server failure when switching identity using stem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035413/general-socks-server-failure-when-switching-identity-using-stem)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48245845/892493 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971593/how-to-only-send-certain-requests-with-tor-in-python/47999800#47999800